# Suppose $f$ is differentiable with $f'(x)>0\;\forall x$ and $f(1)=0$ how can I prove that $F(1)<0$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Suppose $f$ is differentiable with $f'(x)>0\;\forall x$ and $f(1)=0$ how can I prove that $F(1)<0$?

where $F(x)=\int_0^x f(t)dt$ (the primitive integral)

also the function $F$ is tw0-times differentiable?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: What does $f'(x)>0$ mean geometrically about the graph of the function?

Comment: I have thought: derivative positive means the function is increasing over its dominium, then $f(x)<0$ for $x<1$ then integral from 0 to 1 is negative, because the function is negative in this interval? I only want to be more rigorous when explaining this.

Comment: What you have thought is correct!

Comment: Use the angry value theorem to show that $f(x) < 0$ for $x < 1$.